# Do you italicize fictional company names?

Tags: grammar

Generally in fiction writing, you don't italicize company names (even though you would italicize the name of a newspaper).

But what do you do if the company name is fictional, especially a name that is not a real word (Like *Schway*). Italicizing it would make it clearer to the reader that it is a name (and not a typo). It would also make the name easier to read.

What happens if the text has a mix of fictional and real world company names  (e.g. the BBC and *Schway*). It seems a bit odd to have a mix of italics and roman.

Context:

Example:

```
Alice would always go to Adam's restaurant.
[Couple of chapters later]

After leaving Adam's, Angela checked her email. She had got a message from Schway, the famous social network, which was even bigger than Facebook or Twitter.
```

I'm not sure but I feel it might read easier with italics (especially Adam's)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If you or your editor want to use italics for this purpose, for instance in a textbook, you can do so— but by that standard you can use italics for anything you please. As such, it's unclear to me what you're asking. Why is it important to distinguish a fictional from a real name? Why would a fictional company name be more likely to be confused for a typo than a real company name (Google/Googol)? Have you encountered this convention anywhere before? Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/314982/edit) the question to include the context.

Comment: @choster I have added context.

Comment: This isn't really on-topic here. You might like to visit the [writers.se] site.

Comment: @curiousdannii I actually think this is on-topic as it concerns things that would be found in a newspaper style guide (in the section about spelling, punctuation). But it all depends on which style you care about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know of no precedent for italicising company names, for any systematic editorial purpose.  As far as I am aware there is nothing to stop you adopting such a convention as a personal preference, but it would end up being confusing if you plan to alternate between real and invented companies.  And even then, how could you be sure?  How does your decision to italicise your (you believe) invention of ‘Schway’ relate to the well-established ironmongers founded by Mr Schway of Oxford?

That kind of convention seems impossible to guarantee and to sustain. It would seem to be a better idea simply to make the reader clear through your writing as to what ‘exists’ in your diegetic world. There are plenty of famously and painlessly fictional companies, including Dotheboys Hall (Dickens, [*Nicholas Nickleby*](http://www.charlesdickensinfo.com/novels/nicholas-nickleby/)) and Yoyodyne Corporation (in Pynchon's [*The Crying of Lot 49*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crying_of_Lot_49)).  As far as I know the former remains fictional, but Yoyodyne (as well as later figuring in the film [*The Adventures of Buckaroo Banzai Across the Eighth Dimension*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086856/)) has actually been adopted by [at least one real company](http://www.yoyodyneti.com/).

A policy of italicising invented names seems both immediately and increasingly unworkable.

Italicising the name of a newspaper is concerned with conventions of referencing titles, not with regarding such a paper as an organisation.

Comment: +1 for *diegetic*. Learn something new every day, on this site.

Comment: @DanBron Much-delayed PhD in screen narrative. Probably-weird terminology all comes to seem a bit obvious, over time:  what can I say? And therefore _miming_ it will be my next Thing.  _That_ is the extemporaneous moofling that SE evidently needs.